# CRM dynamics 2011 : export Attachments

Tags: email, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow, attachment

I have a workflow that create an email which have attachments files. But when i export the solution and then importe it in a new environment, i can't find those attachments.

Any idees ? how can i import email attachements in the workflow ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the email attachments are not part of the solution, you must update the email activity of the workflow after import.

Answer (score 0):

Attachments/AvtivityMimeAttachment(email)/Notes exist in there own entities.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309364.aspx